# how to format a date inside a reactjs component

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs

I have this snippet inside a react js component

```
 <time dateTime={ this.props.created_at } className="date">{ this.props.user + " • "+ this.props.created_at }</time>
```

turns out that the output is like `luizkowalski • 2014-12-19T15:16:00.274Z`. How can I format this date? can it be done via Rails?

Comment: Unfamiliar with reactjs but if you're able to run Ruby stuff within those `{}` brackets, then you can use `strftime` in front of your `created_at` to achieve any formatting you like.

Comment: I can't run any ruby code here

Comment: Then you should send a formatted `created_at` in your JSON response. And there, you can employ strftime e.g. `obj.created_at.strftime("%d %b %Y")` :) I shall post this as a separate answer.

Comment: That kind of solves the problem, because I want to print the time like "50 minutes ago"

Comment: Cool. Mark my answer the selected one if it answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send a formatted `created_at` within your JSON response. If you're articulating the JSON response (specifying it yourself), this shouldn't be a problem. Otherwise, you will need to overwrite the `to_json` or `as_json` methods within the model to merge your formatted `created_at`

For example:

```
def as_json
  super.merge('created_at' => self.created_at.strftime("%d %b %Y"))
end
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `strftime` method on the Time/DateTime objects in Ruby

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Time.html#method-i-strftime

Comment: I am assuming `this.props.created_at` is being returned to the client side from a Rails server, so just format it prior to returning the response.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a `strftime` javascript library that you can add to your project using `yarn add strftime`. I had an issue getting access to the library using `webpacker` (I'm still learning and adapting from assets pipeline) You can find my question here (including a link to the github link for `strftime` here:

[Rails/Webpack: Can't access a JS library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57006114/rails-webpack-cant-access-a-js-library)

Only problem it seems is that it doesn't like the format that comes from my application which is something else I'll have to solve.