# Rails/Webpack: Can't access a JS library

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I'm trying to access the `strftime` JS library in my Rails application. I've followed the [instructions](https://github.com/samsonjs/strftime#installation) on how to add it using `yarn add` and I've added a `debugger` statement in one of my react components so I can try and access it through the console. `strftime` is not defined and the instructions say this about requiring it:

```
var strftime = require('strftime') // not required in browsers
console.log(strftime('%B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S')) // => April 28, 2011 18:21:08
console.log(strftime('%F %T', new Date(1307472705067))) // => 2011-06-07 18:51:45
```

I believe `require` is a `node.js` thing because you can't "require" code in the browser. It states that its not needed in the browser but the instructions also say to add it as a `<script>` tag but if I have the `webpacker` gem, I should be able to just do something like:

```
import strftime from 'strftime'
```

in my `application.js` file right?

What is required to get access to a library from `node_modules` in my Rails app?

**Edit:**

Some context: This is an existing application running Rails 5.2.3 which is currently being migrated from sprockets/asset pipeline to React components with Webpack(er).

I've updated my `environment.js` file using the answer from @thanhnha1103.

If I open my app in Chrome for example and go to the console and type `strftime` it says `strftime is not defined`. However, if I add a `debugger` instruction in my `application.js` file just after `import strftime from 'strftime'` I get access to two objects called `strftime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__` and `strftime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default`.

Now if I do this in console while the JS has stopped because of debugger:

```
strftime = strftime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__
```

I have access to a function called strftime which is my intended purpose. (I also have to import `strftime` in my react component to get access to this but that's probably as intended. Any ideas about how to make this work out of the box without doing this in my `application.js` file?:

```
import strftime from 'strftime'
strftime = strftime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__
debugger // obviously I'll remove this later but this is for testing purposes.
console.log('Hello World from Webpacker')

// Support component names relative to this directory:
var componentRequireContext = require.context("components", true);
var ReactRailsUJS = require("react_ujs");
ReactRailsUJS.useContext(componentRequireContext);
```

Comment: `import strftime from "strftime";` should work. can you provide a repo?

Comment: @streletss I wish I could but this is my client's application. I cannot share this code online. I could create a rails application from scratch and add `strftime` and test it but I can't guarantee that that would give me the same environment, especially because I'm migrating from sprockets to React/webpacker.

Comment: oh, ok. but still need more info. how did you include 'application.js' and what the actual content of it? what folder structure you have in `javascript/packs`? any errors related to `import` statement?

Comment: Check out my edits. I've included my `application.js` file. More or less the first answer is working but I'll give you a +1 if you can figure out the last part.

Comment: Actually, I've figured out that I don't need to do this if I dont use the debugger command and let the component render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this in your config files:

```
// config/webpack/environment.js

const webpack = require('webpack');

const {environment} = require('@rails/webpacker');

environment.plugins.append(
  'ProvidePlugin-Strftime', // arbitrary name
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    strftime: 'strftime'
  }),
);

module.exports = environment;
```

Comment: This is working more or less now. See my edits because I'm not quite there.

Comment: Nevermind. This is working. I guess I seem to be in a different scope when I use `debugger`.